# Opening diskpart sometimes stops on "In this PC"

Tags: windows, cmd, command, prompt

We are using the cmd to format the SD card: we need to make a partition, resize it and format to FAT, with 32k cluster size.

We are using diskpart for it, because we do need to do it automatically through batch files. But for some reason, diskpart seems to give some problems while opening it:

As soon as I write `diskpart` in the cmd, sometimes it works (and I can read:

```
DISKPART>
```

in a new command window). Sometimes, though, it seems to stuck there: open the new command window, but it does not go further than:

```
Microsoft DiskPart version 6.1.7601
Copyright (C) 1999-2008 Microsoft Corportation.
In this PC: <myPC>
```

with no `DISKPART>` and I cannot use it.

*Note: I translated from Spanish, it may not be the exact text.*

The only "solution" nowadays for me is to reboot the PC. But is there another solution? Cause rebooting the PC is not a feasible one for us.

Comment: It is normal for DISKPART to take some time to start up, it might be up to a minute in some cases.  If it is not starting up at all, there is probably something wrong with your PC, either hardware or software.  (The question might be better suited for Super User.)

Comment: The fact is that it seems to work "at the beggining" properly (like it opens in less than 5 seconds) but some kind of "action" could be causing a problem in the initialization (after using DISKPART for some minutes) and I was looking for this "action".